nx mono repo Daemon process terminated and closed the connection
while the running the nx test it show this error "Daemon process terminated and closed the connection
Please rerun the command, which will restart the daemon.
If you get this error again, check for any errors in the daemon process logs found in: D:\inextlabs\xx-apps.nx\cache\d\daemon.log" i restart the daemon also it not working
I try to restart the daemon it repeated same error

Did you check the logs for errors in "D:\inextlabs\xx-apps.nx\cache\d\daemon.log"?

Try doing
nx repair

If it doesnt work try:
nx reset

Mostly from my eperience it rarely works so post this the thing that has worked for me is:

Update your nx package.
Update your plugins and ensure all are on the same version.
Then go to the project where you wanna run your script and run it.

